# What roles are assigned to TestFlight Beta Testers automatically?

Tags: testflight

The question would be silly, if I am not the Admin role on this account.

Like a zillion times before, I invite an internal tester, add him a role (Customer Support in this case), a users accepts it, but I do not see this user in the list of internal users nor I can add him to test any TestFlight build.

Does anyone know what roles are automatically added to TestFlight Beta Testers internal group? And what to do when Admin cannot add a user to TestFlight build?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but it seems the minimum required is role of Marketer for someone to be able to download the app to test it. Customer support role didn't work for my friend to download it.

Answer (score 10):

According to Apple documentation:

> **Internal Testers**
>
> Each app can be tested by up to 25 members of your team who have been
> assigned the Admin, App Manager, Developer, or Marketer role in iTunes
> Connect. Each member can test on up to 30 devices. Internal testers
> can access all of your beta builds available for testing.

Font: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Note: Users are not automatically added to Test Flight. You also need to enable their account as a "Tester" in App Store Connect Users under the TestFlight section for your app, and the user will need to accept an invite email.

Comment: Just wonderful how the updated docs include the "Technical" role, even though that role doesn't appear on the actual Roles list. :-(